# DotSpatial M and Z values not displaying in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polyline-creation, dotspatial

I'm making a polyline with M and Z values using DotSpatial.

The M an Z values are displayed when the shapefile is dropped in QGIS, but in ArcGIS, though the attribute table indicates that its a PolylineZM shape, only the X&Y shows up in the Edit Sketch Properties, while Z and M are displayed as NaN.

I assume it might be a property that ArcGIS requires, but is having trouble finding. Code below:

```
IFeature myFeature = new Feature();

FeatureSet fs = new FeatureSet(myFeature.FeatureType);

fs.CoordinateType = CoordinateType.M;

List<Coordinate> liVertices = new List<Coordinate>();

for (int i =0; i< 3; i++)
{

  liVertices.Add(new DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate(dEast[i], dNorth[i], dDepth[i], dKp[i]));

}

myFeature = new Feature(liVertices);

fs.CoordinateType = CoordinateType.M;

myFeature.ShapeType.Equals(23);

myFeature.Envelope.HasZ();

myFeature.Envelope.HasM();

myFeature.Envelope.Maximum.M = dMmax;

myFeature.Envelope.Minimum.M = dMmin;

myFeature.UpdateEnvelope();

myFeature.Envelope.SetExtents(dXmin, dYmax, dZmin, dXmax, dYmax, dZmax);

fs.Features.Add(myFeature);

fs.SaveAs("Test.shp", true);
```

Comment: I removed the QGIS tag from your question because it sounds like you are seeing what you expect there, and are seeing other than what you expect only in ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Ah, that's my bad. Sorry!